# textContent not changing when activating function

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, console

i made a function that activates onclick to change my html textContent
here is my javascript code

```js
let num1 = 8
let num2 = 2
document.getElementById("num1-el").textContent = num1
document.getElementById("num2-el").textContent = num2
let sumEl = document.getElementById("num-el")

function add() {
  let result = num1 + num2
  sumEl.textContent = "Sum: " + result
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <span id="num1-el"></span>
  <span id="num2-el"></span>
  <br>
  <button onclick="add()">Add</button>
  <button>Subtract</button>
  <button>Divide</button>
  <button>Multiply</button>
  <br>
  <span id="sum-el">Sum: </span>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

i tried clicking the add button in my live preview on vs code but the

span id="sum-el" doesnt change to the sum of the two numbers it just stays as Sum: when it should say Sum: 10 im new to programming and im doing the freecode camp tutorial for javascript im sorry if this is an easy fix

Comment: Typo: `num-el` should be `sum-el`. Didn't you get an error in the console when you tested this?

Comment: real simple, there is no element id="num-el" on the page. Use your developer console to see the error messages!

Comment: Yes : even in the snippet : "message": "TypeError: sumEl is null"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `sumEl` **has** an **id** `sum-el` and **not** `num-el`.

So change that in **js line 5**.

Comment: Don't post real answers to simple typos.

Comment: I deleted my answer @Barmar :)